# i want the code to say the first word on the first click,the second word on the second click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i want the code to say the first word on the first click,the second word on the second click

here is the code:

```js
var hola = false;
var plus = 0;
var words = ['hola', 'como', 'esta']

function draw() {
  class mouse {
    click() {
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
        plus = plus + 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    textSize(50);
    text(words[0], mouseX, mouseY, 50);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array, as a FIFO data structure (I call it queue here).

By using `.shift()`, you can **pop** the first element from the collection, to print it, and then keep doing that until the collection is empty. (You will need to handle the case where you  try to pop an empty object).

```js
var hola = false;
var plus = 0;
var wordsQueue = ['hola', 'como', 'esta']

function draw() {
  class mouse {
    click() {
      if (mouseIsPressed) {
        plus = plus + 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    textSize(50);
    alert(wordsQueue.shift()); //removes head of queue
  }
}
```

Comment: the three are showing at the same time i want on every click one of them to show up

Answer (score 0):

Just use `plus` to access each element in the array:

```js
var plus = 0;
var words = ['hola', 'como', 'esta'];
document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
  plus++;
  document.write(words[plus % words.length]);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: i don't wana show it in the console i want it to show when i click the mouse on the screen

Comment: Edited @s.rob, any better?